# Can I make printf format floats like C++ streams

Tags: printf, cout

I am comparing the output of two programs, one C the other C++, using `diff`, so the output must be identical.

Is there any way to `printf` a double so that it is formatted as though it was printed using `<< mydouble`.

I am currently using `printf("%g",mydouble)`

Here are some examples of the differences:

```
c: 3.24769e-05 c++: 3.2477e-05
c: 0.0026572   c++: 0.00265721
```

Interestingly the scientific notation has more digits in c, and the decimal notation has more in c++.

Comment: Using `printf` in the C++ might be easier.

Comment: Which part of [the manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) do you have a question about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by using the format specifiers in C.

For example, say you would like to print out only 3 places after the decimal, you could make your printf like so:

```
printf("%.3lf", dub);
```

With a value of `double dub = .0137;` the output would be `0.014`

This would fix the issue with your 2nd case if you want more precision printed you could write:

```
printf("%.8lf", dub);
```

Your output for `double dub = 0.00265721;` would then be `0.00265721`

The case for %g works the same way except the number on the left is included in the calculation. If you wanted the C++ version (the lesser precision I assume) then your code would look like this:

```
double dub = .0000324769;
printf("%.5g", dub);
```

Which yields `3.2477e-05`

Comment: On my system at least, changing `%g` to `%.5g` makes the output decimal instead of scientific for certain values.

Comment: oh okay .4 is what i needed -- duh